# How compile training neural network as stand-alone app in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, mcc

I want to [compile](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) my MATLAB application that uses [neural networks](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network/) to a stand-alone application, but as you know MATLAB can't compile training neural network as stand-alone and can only compile already trained neural networks.

The core of my application consists of training a neural network on an imported data. How can I do that? Is there an alternative way to do this? My MATLAB version is R2014a.

I tried using `deploytool` for compiling, but according to the MATLAB Compiler documentation:

```
THIS CAN BE COMPILED
  * Pre-trained network
  * command line functions

THIS CANNOT BE COMPILED
  * All other command line functionality
  * All GUIs provided with toolbox
  * Simulink blocks
  * gensim
```

So we get error after compiling the app if we have functions like `newff` or `patternnet` or other training functions in our code.

I know this is [a limitation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92893-is-it-possible-to-compile-matlab-files-that-call-neural-network-toolbox-functions-into-stand-alone-a) of the MATLAB Compiler and I [searched](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/247626) for solutions for months but I didn't find any workarounds or alternative ways.

Apparently there is a function added to newer versions of MATLAB for using trained neural networks in MATLAB compiler: [Deploy Neural Network Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/deploy-neural-network-functions-and-objects.html).

Comment: This question is not clear at all. Please add a minimal working code containing something that you cannot build, describe how you tried to build it (with the deploytool, or also with matlab coder) and what happened when you tried. Then people may be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help not only giving negative reputation score to me :-) .

Comment: I think the question is much better now. That being said, usually crossposting is not preferred. When you do make sure to add the link. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110434/how-compile-training-neural-network-as-stand-alone-app-in-matlab

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know. I deleted that post.

Comment: sounds like it is locked down on purpose.  Maybe go for an open source alternative: i.e. http://sourceforge.net/projects/octnnettb/,  there are others to: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1GGGE_en-gbGB525GB525&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=open%20source%20matlabs

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we run octave codes in MATLAB?

Comment: If we have all alternative packages for neural network in MATLAB (free or commercial) is so good.

Comment: @QED. We have some `##` symbols in your recommended package that MATLAB can't read. What is the problem?

Comment: @user2991243 i think it can read most matlab, but i've not heard anyone trying to it the other way around, sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bottom line is that MATLAB Compiler only [supports](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html) deploying **pre-trained** neural networks.

> **Neural Network Toolbox**
>
> Can be compiled:
>
> - Pre-trained network command line functions
>
> Cannot be compiled:
>
> - All other command line functionality
> - Apps and UIs
> - Simulink blocks
> - `gensim`

This means you cannot [`mcc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/mcc.html)-compile functions with training functionality (anything containing [TRAIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/train.html), [ADAPT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/adapt.html), etc...), you can only deploy functions that evaluate/simulate an already trained network object ([SIM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/sim.html) function and the like).

---

For the supported scenario (deploying a pre-trained network), there are a couple of ways to go about it:

## 1) [save/load pre-trained network object to a MAT-file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101939-how-can-i-compile-a-pre-trained-neural-network-into-a-standalone-application-using-the-matlab-compil#answer_111286)

In a normal MATLAB session, load the training data you have, then create and train a neural network using desired settings (keep tuning the network parameters until you are satisfied with the result). Finally save the network object to disk (export as variable in a MAT-file).

```
% sample regression dataset
[x,y] = simplefit_dataset();

% feed-forward neural network (one hidden layer with 4 neurons)
net = fitnet(4);
net = configure(net, x, y);            % configure net to match data
net.trainParam.showWindow = false;     % dont show training GUI
net.trainParam.showCommandLine = true; % display output in command line
net.trainParam.show = 1;               % display output every iteration

% train networks (data is divided into train/validation/test sets)
net = init(net);           % initialize network weights
[net,tr] = train(net, x, y);

% save pre-trained network to MAT-file
save('pretrained_network.mat', 'net')
```

Next create a deployable function that loads the saved network, and uses it to predict the output given some test data (note the use of [`%#function` pragma](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/function.html) line):

#### simulateSavedNet.m

```
function y_hat = simulateSavedNet(x)
    % this is a special pragma for MATLAB Compiler
    % used to declare "network" class as dependency in deployed mode
    %#function network

    % load pre-trained network
    S = load('pretrained_network.mat', 'net');
    net = S.net;

    % predict outcome given input data
    %y_hat = net(x);
    y_hat = sim(net, x);
end
```

## 2) [Generate a standalone M-function from pre-trained network](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/deploy-neural-network-functions-and-objects.html)

You can generate a standalone MATLAB function from a pre-trained network object using [`genFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/genfunction.html), which can then be used to simulate network output. This functionality was introduced in MATLAB R2013b.

It will basically hard-code network settings, structure, and weights all in one M-function. The generated function is fully compatible with MATLAB Compiler [`mcc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/mcc.html) (compiled into one of the supported targets) as well as MATLAB Coder [`codegen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html) (converted to standalone C/C++ code).

```
% generate standalone M-function from the trained net
genFunction(net, 'simulateStandaloneNet.m', 'MatrixOnly','yes', 'ShowLinks','no')
```

Here is the code for the generated function:

> [simulateStandaloneNet.m](http://pastebin.com/qAvrXdxA)

## 3) Manually simulate the pre-trained network

For simple static neural networks (feed-forward and the like), it is relatively easy to evaluate a pre-trained network and simulate its output (the hard part is training them!).

I've showed how to do this in [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2420953/97160) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11853201/97160). You basically extract the learned weights from the network, then plug those numbers into the transfer functions, feed it the input, and compute the propagated outputs (one layer at-a-time). You will have to take care of applying any pre-/post- processing on the data and use the same transfer functions in each layer.

In fact, this is basically what `genFunction` does in the previous approach, only it is automated and handles all cases (works for all kinds of neural networks, not just feed-forward ANNs).

Here is an example from the network trained above:

#### simulateManualNet.m

```
function y_hat = simulateManualNet(x)
    % pre-trained feed-forward neural network
    % contains one hidden layer with 4 neurons, 1D input, 1D output
    % We assume the default transfer functions, preprocessing, etc..

    % The following hardcoded values were obtained
    % from net.IW, net.LW, net.b properties using MAT2STR

    % hidden layer weights/biases
    b1 = [6.0358701949521; 2.72569392497815; 0.584267717191459; -5.1615078566383];
    W1 = [-14.0019194910639; 4.90641117353245; -15.2282807645331; -5.26420794868803];
    % output layer weights/biases
    b2 = -0.756207251486408;
    W2 = [0.548462643231606 -0.435802343861239 -0.085111261420613 -1.13679228253379];

    % scale input
    in = mapFcn(x);

    % hidden layer
    hid = hiddenLayerTransferFcn(bsxfun(@plus, W1*in, b1));

    % output layer
    out = outputLayerTransferFcn(W2*hid + b2);

    % inverse scale output
    y_hat = mapInverseFcn(out);
end

function xx = mapFcn(x)
    % linear mapping from [mn,mx] to [-1,1]
    mn = 0; mx = 9.97628374728129;
    xx = (x - mn)*2 / (mx - mn) - 1;
end
function x = mapInverseFcn(xx)
    % inverse linear mapping from [-1,1] to [mn,mx]
    mn = 0; mx = 10;
    x = (xx + 1) * (mx - mn)/2 + mn;
end
function out = hiddenLayerTransferFcn(in)
    % Hyperbolic tangent sigmoid transfer function
    out = tanh(in);
end
function out = outputLayerTransferFcn(in)
    % Linear transfer function
    out = in;
end
```

## 4) [Generate Simulink block from pre-trained network, and convert it using Simulink Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/deploy-neural-network-simulink-diagrams.html)

The idea here is to generate a Simulink block from the pre-trained network using [`gensim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/gensim.html), then convert the generated block into a standalone C/C++ application using [Simulink Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder/) (formerly known as Real-Time Workshop). Compiling neural network to Simulink blocks was introduced in R2010b.

I'm not a Simulink expert, so I'll leave it to you to explore [this approach](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92893-is-it-possible-to-compile-matlab-files-that-call-neural-network-toolbox-functions-into-stand-alone-a#answer_102243):

```
gensim(net)
```

---

In each approach above (first three anyway), the idea is to compile the `simulate` functions into one of the supported targets by MATLAB Compiler (standalone executable, shared library, Java package, .NET assembly) then deploy the generated component.

*(Actually approach #2 and #3 can also be converted into C/C++ source code using MATLAB Coder `codegen`).*

Here is how to compile each into a shared library using `mcc` command (you could use [`deploytool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/deploytool.html) if you like):

```
% 1) saved network
mcc -v -W cpplib:libANN -T link:lib -N -p nnet simulateSavedNet.m -a pretrained_network.mat

% 2) standalone simulation function (genFunction)
mcc -v -W cpplib:libANN -T link:lib -N simulateStandaloneNet

% 3) standalone simulation function (manual)
mcc -v -W cpplib:libANN -T link:lib -N simulateManualNet
```

To check the resulting DLLs, below is a C++ test program that links against the produced shared library:

```
% 1)
mbuild -output test_savedNet -DSIMFCN=simulateSavedNet -I. test_net.cpp libANN.lib

% 2)
mbuild -output test_standaloneNet -DSIMFCN=simulateStandaloneNet -I. test_net.cpp libANN.lib

% 3)
mbuild -output test_manualNet -DSIMFCN=simulateManualNet -I. test_net.cpp libANN.lib
```

The code for the test program:

#### test_net.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "libANN.h"

// choose one!
//#define SIMFCN simulateSavedeNet
//#define SIMFCN simulateStandaloneNet
//#define SIMFCN simulateManualNet

int main()
{
    // initialize MCR and lib
    if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0))  {
        std::cerr << "could not initialize the application" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(!libANNInitialize()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not initialize the library" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    try {
        // create input data (1x5 vector)
        double x[] = {1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0};
        mwArray in(1, 5, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
        in.SetData(x, 5);

        // predict network output by simulating network
        mwArray out;
        SIMFCN(1, out, in);
        double y[5];
        out.GetData(y, 5);

        // show result
        std::cout << "y = net(x)" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "y = \n" << out << std::endl;

    } catch (const mwException& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected error thrown" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 

    // cleanup
    libANNTerminate();   
    mclTerminateApplication();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the output of the resulting programs, compared against the original network object and the source M-functions:

```
>> net([1 3 5 7 9])
ans =
    9.5620    7.7851    7.2716    6.1647    2.4073
>> simulateSavedNet([1 3 5 7 9])
ans =
    9.5620    7.7851    7.2716    6.1647    2.4073
>> simulateStandaloneNet([1 3 5 7 9])
ans =
    9.5620    7.7851    7.2716    6.1647    2.4073
>> simulateManualNet([1 3 5 7 9])
ans =
    9.5620    7.7851    7.2716    6.1647    2.4073

>> !test_savedNet.exe
y = net(x) 
y =  
9.5620    7.7851    7.2716    6.1647    2.4073 

>> !test_standaloneNet.exe
y = net(x) 
y =  
9.5620    7.7851    7.2716    6.1647    2.4073 

>> !test_manualNet.exe
y = net(x) 
y =  
9.5620    7.7851    7.2716    6.1647    2.4073
```

This ended up being a long post, but I wanted to cover all possible cases for this question and future ones :) HTH

Comment: btw if you try to compile a function containing both TRAIN and SIM, it will complete successfully, but it will throw an error when you invoke the compiled function. Here is an example I tried: http://pastebin.com/YnEZeAFg

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Now as you said this is a big limitation in practical works to use a pre-traiend neural network in stand-alone applications. We should find a way to get rid of this limitation. With using MATLAB or other alternative codes in this area that we can use.

Answer (score 2):

It is unfortunately indeed correct that you cannot create a standalone neural network program via the deploytool (so with matlab compiler).

**Alternatives**:

1. You can first train a network, and then build the standalone program, but it seems like you want to do the training after its creation.
2. You can look into matlab coder; this is basically 'the other way' to create programs from matlab. I have not been able to find whether it supports neural networks, but you could contact the mathworks if you are considering this option.
3. Consider not making a standalone program. Depending on your needs you could for example call matlab from a different program or from the command line to do its job.

Comment: Yes. That's true. We have same limitation in MATLAB coder. I'm searching for other alternative toolboxes (third-party) for neural network. For example we have `libsvm` as an alternative free toolbox for SVM toolbox of MATLAB.

Comment: @user2991243 I think the [matlab file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=neural+network) will be your best bet then. Unfortunately I can't judge whether it contains what you need.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to deploy the network training functionality of Neural Network Toolbox using either the deployment products (MATLAB Compiler, MATLAB Builder products) or the code generation products (MATLAB Coder etc).

You might look into using a third-party toolbox for neural networks such as [Netlab](http://www.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab/). Netlab doesn't include all the neural network functionality of Neural Network Toolbox, but it includes most typically-used functionality, and quite a few extra methods that are covered better by Statistics Toolbox, such as K-means clustering.

I'm not aware of any technical problems in deploying Netlab functionality, and I believe it's licensed under a BSD open-source license, so you should be able to include and redistribute it with your project with no problems.

---

Edit: As of R2016b, it is now possible to compile network training functionality from Neural Network Toolbox (or Deep Learning Toolbox as it is now known).

Comment: Thank you for answer Sam. It is very confusing. Why we have something like open-source `Libsvm` for support vector machines for MATLAB with that strong supporting and updating but there isn't any good alternative neural network for MATLAB ! I didn't find any commercial neural network package for MATLAB until now so!